# How to quit MATLAB if syntax error in command line code (option -r)

Tags: matlab

I need to run MATLAB in batch mode and would like to catch all possible errors. The following code

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "try, x=y; catch ME, disp(getReport(ME)); end; exit"
```

works fine and MATLAB correctly complains

```
Undefined function or variable 'y'.
```

However, for syntax errors such as this

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "try, x:=y; catch ME, disp(getReport(ME)); end; exit"
```

MATLAB says

```
 try, x:=y; catch ME, disp(getReport(ME)); end; exit
        |
Error: Incorrect use of '=' operator. To assign a value to a variable, use '='. To compare values for equality, use '=='.
>>
```

and *pauses* at the command prompt. A brute force method to prevent this behavior is

```
echo "exit" | matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "try, x:=y; catch ME, disp(getReport(ME)); end; exit"
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue? Thanks.

MATLAB Version: 9.5 (R2018b), OS: Linux 4.12.14 (OpenSUSE)

Comment: I think this is because the first one is a run-time error that happens while matlab actually runs the code. In the second one the interpreter will not run the code at all, it refuses to execute as the syntax is unknown, so it never gets to the try-catch statement, thus not exiting.

Comment: You can wrap the dubious command in `eval`: `matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r "try, eval('x:=y'); catch ME, disp(getReport(ME)); end; exit"`

Comment: You should use the `-r` option only with scripts, and only with scripts you've properly debugged.